# How do I make bit value from SQL Server Stored Procedure clickable to update?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I have a table for projects that has a `bit` value for whether the project is still active or not. I created a stored procedure that pulls the project name and the value for the project (`0` for inactive, `1` for active). When I display it on my webpage, the `bit` values show up in checkboxes (which is good because I would like to be able to update those values with a button).

The problem is that I'm unable to click or unclick them.

How could I pull my data correctly so that the checkboxes for the project name is clickable to be updated?

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
public void loadProj()
{
    SqlConnection con;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjDB"].ConnectionString;

    using (con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
         con.Open();

         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetProjActive", con);
         SqlDataAdapter sa = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
         callStoredProcedure(cmd, sa);
         sa.Fill(dt);

         GridView.DataSource = dt;
         GridView.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a `asp:TemplateField` in your `GridView` columns, with a `asp:CheckBox` control inside this template.

**Setting the `CheckBox` value**: The Boolean database value should be bound into the `CheckBox` using the `OnRowDataBound` event.

**Changing the database value**: Register a `OnCheckedChanged` event on the template field's `CheckBox` control.

---

**HTML markup:**

```
<asp:GridView   ID="gv" 
                runat="server" 
                DataSourceID="..."
                OnRowDataBound="gv_DataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chk_selection" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="chk_selection__CheckedChanged" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        ....
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Code behind:**

```
protected void gv_DataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // Get this row's CheckBox control
    CheckBox chkSelector = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chk_selection");

    // Cast the database boolean value and set the checkbox's Checked property
    chkSelector.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "bool_field"));
}

protected void chk_selection__CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Update your database
}
```

Comment: My bit field in the database is named "isActive". I tried replacing it with "bool_field" but it's throwing a null error. Am I missing something?

Comment: @vanillacoke9191 Could it be that some of your rows have a `NULL` value in this field ?

Comment: I have the values either as a 0 or a 1. Would a 0 be considered null? :\

Comment: No, That's not the case. What is the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Would I still need to set the DataSourceID="..." if I already specified the database connection in loadProj()?

Comment: At what line are you getting this message ?

Comment: chkSelector.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "isActive"));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151183/discussion-between-koby-douek-and-vanillacoke9191).